# File PATH is changed when docker image is built

Tags: node.js, docker

So I have a NodeJS app that will download a file when the endpoint is hit. When I run my app locally it will download the file just fine, but when I build and run the Docker container I get an error saying "no such file or directory" because /app was added to the beginning of the file path

Here is the route file,

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const filePath = "C:/Users/grips/projects/myApp/src"

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const file = `${filePath}/data.txt`;
    console.log("file:", file)
    res.download(file, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error:", err)
        } else {
            console.log("File Downloaded!")
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Here is the DockerFile

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "src/main.js"]
```

and here is the logs that contain the error

```
Error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/C:/Users/grips/projects/myApp/src/data.txt'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/app/C:/Users/grips/projects/myApp/src/data.txt',
  expose: false,
  statusCode: 404,
  status: 404
}
```

Comment: The variable `filePath` doesn't begin with a slash, so it's interpreted as a relative path relative to the current directory.  (Linux paths don't have DOS-style drive letters, and the container has its own isolated filesystem that doesn't know about your `C:\Users\...` host path.)

Comment: @DavidMaze So would I need to upload the file to container in order for the download functionality to work properly?

Comment: A container has an isolated filesystem and can't normally access files on your host.  This might mean it's more appropriate to run your application outside a container.  You alternately could [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the host directory into the container, but you'd still need to use the container paths and not the host paths in your configuration.